# A question about the range of influence of the grease pencil sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting, grease-pencil

I drew lines on the surface.
And I tried to modify the line on one side in Sculpt Mode.
But the lines on the opposite side move together.
Can you solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While in sculpt mode, you can press C to circle select only the vertices you want to edit, confirm with right click, then enable this button to limit the sculpt to selected vertices.

[image]